# What if I don't wait for an async method when calling it for a synchronous method in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have two method that asynchronously send otp via email and sms.

Now, I call them from my synchronous event handler method.

This works fine. I receive OTP both via SMS and email. But I wonder is it correct or I should make my event async and await for both methods to send otp.

**Please note that I don't require any results/ return values from my async methods. I just need them to do their part.**

I have searched for answers over the web but none could clear my doubt. 
Kindly help. I am new to async/await.

```
public async Task SendEmail(int otp) {}
public async Task SendSMS(int otp) {}

protected void SendOTP_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // Do Something with database...
    int otp=1234;
    SendEmail(otp);
    SendSMS(otp);
}
```

Comment: In this case you're going to fire-and-forget both methods. If they throw exceptions, you will never know, or you will have to add proper exception handling inside those methods. `SendOTP_OnClick` will call both SendEmail and SendSMS, both should return when they are themselves awaiting an async operation, and SendOTP_OnClick will then continue, before those methods have completed.

Comment: Basically, the execution will continue before they complete. If you don't need any return values you are fine, but you won't know for sure when will they finish. If it is the long-running task, you might want to await them as you may need that information for some other stuff.

Comment: Hi Lasse and Harun, in my case I have exception handling code inside each of the methods individually, where I log the exceptions. So If don't await them in **SendOTP_OnClick**, my mail and sms will get sent? (provided no exception arises)

Answer (score 2):

> Please note that I don't require any results/ return values from my async methods. I just need them to do their part.

Do you need to know *whether* they do their part? The result of a method not only includes the return value, but also an indication of whether it succeeded (returns successfully) or failed (throws an exception). If you need to know whether those methods fail, then you can't use fire-and-forget.

> I wonder is it correct or I should make my event async and await for both methods to send otp.

The vast majority of the time, developers do want to know whether their methods fail, so it is better to `await`.

Comment: Hi Stephen. I just want to be sure that they have done their part, i.e. succeeded. In my case, its sending a sms and an email. If they throw an exception, i have exception handling code inside each of them individually using a try catch block, where I log exceptions.

Comment: @Abhishek: Even if they're doing their own exception logging, how does your application (or your application host) know when they're done, so it knows when it's OK to exit? ASP.NET will regularly restart your application, and if you use fire-and-forget, then your email/SMS methods can be terminated. Without notification, exception, or logging.